# Dajax not working

Tags: django, django-templates, dajaxice, dajax

Dajax is not working, I am not able to understand why. I am using Django 1.7

My ajax.py file looks this:

```
from dajax.core import Dajax
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register
def jmc_foundation_tower_number(request, option):

    print("It works!")
```

My template call is as follows:

```
<div class='col-lg-3'>
  <select id='id_tower_number' name='tower_number' onchange="Dajaxice.core.views.jmc_foundation_tower_number(Dajax.process, {'option':$this.value})" onclick="Dajaxice.core.views.jmc_foundation_tower_number(Dajax.process, {'option':$this.value})" class='form-control'>
       {% for tower in towers %}
          <option value='{{ tower }}'>{{ tower }}</option>
       {% endfor %}
   </select>
</div>
```

My urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover, dajaxice_config
dajaxice_autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index$', 'core.views.index', name='index'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently javascript function names with underscores('_') don't work when using functions like onclick.It's better to use functions like somefunction() instead of some_function() to make Dajax work.

Answer (score 1):

**django-dajax** and **django-dajaxice**

> **Should I use django-dajax or django-dajaxice?**
>
> In a word, No. I created these projects 4 years ago as a cool tool in
>   order to solve one specific problems I had at that time.
>
> These days using these projects is a bad idea.
>   (...)
>   If you want to use this project, you are probably wrong. You should
>   stop couplig your interface with your backend or... in the long term
>   it will explode in your face.

[jorgebastida/django-dajax](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax)

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example to make Helloworld using dajax

**models.py:**

```
 from django.db import models
 from dajax.core import Dajax
 from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
 @dajaxice_register
 def say_hello(request,value):
    dajax = Dajax()
    dajax.alert(value)
    return dajax.json()
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'server.views.index', name='index'),
```

where "server" in server.views.index is the application name inside your project

in index.html file you have to use a jquery function to call this dajax request as following
**index.html:**

```
 <html>
    <script>
      function print_helloworld(){
                var value = Dajaxice.server.models.say_hello(Dajax.process,{'value':'Hello World!'});
            }
    </script>
    <body>
       <button id='mybtn' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='print_helloworld()'>Hello World</button>
    </body>
 </html>
```

if you need to access the index file from public ip you have to add the {% csrf_token %} token before button